# Conversion of JPEG to SVG in Android

Tags: android

I want to know how to convert JPEG files to SVG files in Android?
Or can I convert PDF into SVG format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG is a raster/bitmap format. SVG is a vector format. Going from bitmap to vector is not a trivial task, as a vector format describes shapes and attributes in an XML format. At the very best, a vector representation of a bitmap would be wildly inefficient.

Perhaps you can give an idea of what you are trying to do, and someone can help with the larger problem?

Comment: k .thank you..actually in my project we are using JPEG and i want to use svg in place of JPEG.. and i have i tried with tinyline for svg renderring .it is working fine but i am able to display only some svg files up to 20KB..so i thought to convert the JPEG to SVG foramt...